# Ruby - Version 2.0.0 installed using RVM but not showing under update-alternatives

Tags: ruby

I just installed ruby 2.0.0 using RVM.

```
u2@u2-VirtualBox:~/tools$ rvm use 2.0.0-p353 --default
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353
```

but I am unable to see/set 2.0.0 as the default Ruby version using update-alternatives. Aptana is using version 1.9.1 as a result

```
u2@u2-VirtualBox:~/tools$ update-alternatives --config ruby
There are 2 choices for the alternative ruby (providing /usr/bin/ruby).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1   51        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/ruby1.8     50        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1   51        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to register the installed version as an alternative provider for `/usr/bin/ruby`. Do it with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ruby ruby /path/to/ruby/2.0/executable
```

Then, you can call `update-alternatives --config ruby` as usual.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I had to add the priority at the end as an additional parameter.